# Multi get returns source as null after bulk update

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elastic search multi get for reading documents after bulk update. Its returning some document sources as null.

```
 MultiGetRequestBuilder builder = client.prepareMultiGet();

 builder.setRefresh(true);

 builder.add(indexName, type, idsList);

 MultiGetResponse multiResponse = builder.execute().actionGet();

 for (MultiGetItemResponse response : multiResponse.getResponses())
 {
         String customerJson = response.getResponse().getSourceAsString();
         System.out.println("customerJson::" + customerJson);
 }
```

Any issues in my code? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "some return sources as null", I assume the get response is marking them as not existing..?

If that's the case, then maybe :

1. some indexation request in the bulk are failing dur to mapping/random error.
2. You need to refresh your index between the indexation and the multiget (i.e : your docs are not available for search yet)

   transportClient.admin().indices().prepareRefresh(index).execute();

good luck

EDIT : You answered your own question in the comment, but for readability's sake : when using get or multiget, if a routing key was used when indexing, it must be specified again during the get, else, a wrong shard is determined using default routing and the get fails.

Comment: Thanks. Instead of refreshing the index, I am using  builder.setRefresh(true); this will refresh these documents alone right?

Comment: Actually, yes. I only use the instruction I wrote, so I did not notice you were indeed refreshing, sorry. Case n°1, then? Else, I'm afraid I'm out of ideas, right now.

Comment: I am using routing. I did not set routing. Is that a problem? If we dont set routing, ES will search in all shards right?

Comment: Ah ! The routing, that's right. I never use it myself, so I forgot, but I've read on the mailing list that you have to specify the routing key that was issued when indexing to retreive your document with a GET. Else, It will use the default routing and search on the wrong shard. That's the kind of errors that can drive you nuts indeed.